# Error in deleteing Java Temp file using Ghost4j sample code

Tags: java, macos

Hi I tried to run http://ghost4j.sourceforge.net/highlevelapisamples.html PDF to PS sample code and it produce this error for me "ERROR: Temporary file /var/folders/8a/8a7E-LirFfeAJh+EC93W4U+++TY/-Tmp-/ghost4j/java.io.FileOutputStream@252f09991304994155878469 cannot be deleted" has anyone encounter this before and currently I am running on mac. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hi I had the same problem, but on windows 7..but I think is for the same reason.

problem was that ghost4j couldn't find the ghostscript libraries so it was failing here

```
result = GhostscriptLibrary.instance.gsapi_set_stdio(getNativeInstanceByRef().getValue(), stdinCallback, stdoutCallback, stderrCallback);
```

when trying to initialise the ghostscript libraries.

So I moved the library files to the directory in which I imported the sources.
As I'm running a 64 bit system I also had to change their name in "GhostscriptLibrary.java".

I found the library files installing ghostscript from http://downloads.ghostscript.com/public/

I'm quite sure is not the best way of solving the problem, but it worked for me.

hope it will help you.